# How to access getter method in calling Java class or Java interface using lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

Using JDK 1.8 and the following lombok version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

Have the following Java interface:

```
package com.myapp.bridge;

public interface MyBridge {
    
    public void run();

}
```

---

Implementing class:

```
package com.myapp.bridge;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class MyBridgeHandler implements MyBridge {
    
    @Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    public String value;

    public void run() {

        String msg = "hello";
        setValue(msg);
        
        // This works and prints hello ten times.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           System.out.println(getValue());
        }

    } 
}
```

---

Calling class:

```
package com.myapp.bridge;

import lombok.Getter;

public class App {
    
    @Getter 
    private MyBridge bridge = new MyBridgeHandler();

    public void printValue() {
        // IntelliJ IDEA doesn't seem to let me access this getter? 
        String aValue = getBridge().getValue();
        System.out.println(aValue); 
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        App app = new App();
        app.printValue();

    }
}
```

---

Question(s):

1. How do I obtain / access the `MyBridgetHandler.getValue()` method inside my calling class
   (IntelliJ IDEA's code completion doesn't even display / or opt for this method after I put a dot after `getBridge().` inside my `printValue` method)?
2. Should it be placed inside the `MyBridge` interface? If so, how would the implementation look like?

---

Note, this is not an IntelliJ specific question as my other POJOs have lombok-based `@getter` & `@setter` annotations and work inside calling classes via IntelliJ IDEA.

Am able to see `hello` be printed to stdout 10 times so it is getting set.

Seems like a visibility / accessibility issue.

Comment: Your getter is a class method, not static. Main is static. New up an instance and call the getter on _it_.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Yes, this is not an IntelliJ lombok issue, like I stated that I have other POJOs using lombok and am able to access those POJOs accessor & mutator methods via IntelliJ.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Sorry, in the actual codebase where I am trying to access the ```getValue()``` method, its inside non-static method (just used ```public static void main (String [] args)```) to make my question seem simpler. Just edited it appropriately.

Comment: you dont need getters or setters in your main method. you already instantiated a MyBridge object and assigned it to bridge. You just need to call `bridge.getValue()`

Comment: @NathanToulbert - Very true... Thanks but I think the Architect / previous developer did that for readability. Will confer with him / her during the pull requests code review.

Comment: then why instantiate MyBridge? You're not using it.

Comment: @NathanToulbert - like I told you, I didn’t write this code... Will see why they wrote it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed / found the solution...

Inside the `MyBridge` interface, I added the following method:

```
package com.myapp.bridge;

public interface MyBridge {
    
    public void run();
  
    String getValue();
}
```

---

Implemented it like this inside `MyBridgeHandler` Java class:

```
package com.myapp.bridge;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class MyBridgeHandler implements MyBridge {
    
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    public String value;

    public void run() {

        String msg = "hello";
        setValue(msg);
        
        // This works and prints hello ten times.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           System.out.println(getValue());
        }
    } 

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    } 
}
```

---

Voila! I am able to access it now inside the `App.printValue()` method.

Comment: FYI, you can implement interface methods using the annotation too. There is no need that an interface method must be explicit declared `public String getValue()`

Comment: @Michael - This is the gist of my original question... 

After placing the ```@Getter``` inside ```MyBridgeHandler``` above ```String value```, the compiler complains:
```Error:(8, 5) java: getValue() in com.myapp.bridge.MyBridgeHandler cannot implement getValue() in com.myapp.bridge.MyBridge
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public```

Can you please show me some code?

Comment: ofc, you cannot use `@Getter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)` because the interface demands it be public. But you can just use `@Getter` (default is public)

Comment: @micheal "the interface demands it be public." Where are you getting this? It doesnt have a modifier in the interface. That defaults to package level in Java. The code in the question should have worked. Looks like a Lombok thing to me. Intellij and Eclipse both occasionally put out wierd errors related to lombok. My workaround is to use both IDEs and switch between them when this happens. The other will almost always not have the same issue. Although I have experienced getting completely different false errors in each at the same time.

Comment: Why did you even use the getter for `bridge`? You don't need to use a getter to access a class scoped property in the same class as the method. That was the reason for my original answer. Using a getter like that makes no sense at all. You are adding many unneeded lines of code across multiple files for nothing. Square wheel. I am honestly curious as to why you would want to use a getter here. Same w/ `setValue(msg)`. Should be `this.value = msg;` , although that one isn't really hurting anything. The other one (getBridge()), however, caused this issue. The checker didn't like the double @.